How to determine if load time weaving is getting used on Spring Boot?
I am using Spring Boot 3.0.12. To enable load-time weaving.
A reproducible example is placed here. (branch - aspect). To reproduce the issue do
curl --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/hello'

I have created an aop.xml under META-INF like below
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="com.example.helloworld.aspects.DaoExceptionHandler"/>

    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
      <include within="com.example.helloworld.*"/>
    </weaver>
  </aspects>
</aspectj>

I am starting the application with javaagent:/Users/dm/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.20/aspectjweaver-1.9.20.jar.
Below dependencies are added in my pom.xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.20</version>
    </dependency>

My aspect code is like below
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class DaoExceptionHandler {
  @AfterThrowing(
      pointcut =
          "execution(* *(..)) &&"
              + " @annotation(com.example.helloworld.utils.HandleDaoException)",
      throwing = "ex")
  public void handle(RuntimeException ex) {
    log.error("Exception received on dao", ex);
    throw JooqUtil.mapException(ex);
  }
}

My usage of @HandleDaoException is like below
@Component
public class DaoImpl {
  @HandleDaoException
  public void getError() {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test");
  }
}

During my application startup, I see logs like below
2024-04-23T16:21:08.770+05:30  INFO 33973 --- [           main] c.e.helloworld.HelloWorldApplication     : Started HelloWorldApplication in 0.797 seconds (process running for 1.13)
[MethodUtil@4b627298] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.20 built on Tuesday Aug 15, 2023 at 23:35:34 PDT
[MethodUtil@4b627298] info register classloader sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil@4b627298
[MethodUtil@4b627298] info using configuration /Users/debrajmanna/code/java/github/spring-boot-hello-world/target/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[MethodUtil@4b627298] info register aspect com.example.helloworld.aspects.DaoExceptionHandler

When I annotate any method @HandleDaoException, aspect is working correctly I see logs like below
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test
    at com.example.helloworld.dao.DaoImpl.getError(DaoImpl.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at com.example.helloworld.dao.DaoImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getError(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.helloworld.controller.HelloWorldController.sendGreetings(HelloWorldController.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
...

If remove -javaagent from my application startup command and also specify @EnableAspectJAutoProxy then also I see the above stack-trace when DaoExceptionHandler is invoked.
My understanding is without load time weaving spring defaults to CGLIB proxies. From the above exception stack trace it looks like CGLIB proxies are still getting used even though load time weaving is enabled. If my understanding is wrong then is there a way for me to know if load time weaving is working properly in spring or not?

It would be good to have a minimal reproducer for this problem. The log clearly shows that the AspectJ weaver is active when you run with -javaagent. I have no idea how JOOQ works internally and whether it uses CGLIB or not, maybe it is related to your question. If I could reproduce the situation and attach a debugger to a demo application, it would be much easier to answer your question.

Ok, I will try to have a reproducible example and update the question.

@kriegaex A reproducible example is placed here. I may be doing something basic wrong. In the above example sending a curl --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/hello' will cause the aspect to get invoked.  I have updated the question accordingly with the reproducer.

Spring defaults to CGLIB in your example because the bean has no interface. Otherwise it would use regular dynamic proxies

In this case, aop is still proxy based either cglib or jdk dynamic proxy which is the spring default as per my understanding. I am looking for a way to enable aspectj load time weaving in a spring application.

Your MCVE does not build. package com.example.helloworld.service does not exist. Class HelloWorldController imports com.example.helloworld.service.Profile, which is missing.

@NicoVanBelle, what you are saying refers to Spring AOP. We are talking about native AspectJ, which does not use any proxies at all.

aop.xml is also empty. I am trying to locally fix both problems to get the project running locally. Next time, you should test your sample project before publishing the link.

It gets worse and worse. The aspect, DAO impl and annotation are also empty. How is this fragmentary project meant to reproduce anything?

@kriegaex I'm aware but the assumption of OP was wrong that by default Spring always uses CGLIB. That assumption is only correct when you pass the proxyTargetClass=true option. Otherwise it will try to use standard Java interface-based proxies.

I apologise. Somehow my local commit did not go through. I am pushing it in.

@kriegaex I have pushed it. All code should be there now in the aspect branch

@NicoVanBelle I meant that by default spring aop uses proxy which can be CGLIB or jdk dynamic proxy (based on the proxyTargetClass value as you pointed out). But here I was trying to use AspectJ load-time weaving in a spring boot app.

You made two mistakes in your project. I fixed them in this PR:

Do not use @Import({ DaoExceptionHandler.class }), because it makes Spring treat the native AspectJ aspect like a Spring @Configuration class, falsely creating a special type of CGLIB proxy for it. That CGLIB proxy is not a regular Spring AOP proxy, but a different type for Spring configs with a different behaviour. See here for an explanation. Anyway, you do not need that, and it is also wrong.

Make sure to set the correct aspect weaving scope com.example.helloworld..*, where the double-dot notation includes sub-packages, too.



Meta comment to all future readers: See, this is why I always ask for a complete, minimal reproducer. The question does not contain enough information to be answered, e.g. the @Import annotation is missing. I would never have expected to find it in the GitHub project. But with the cloned project, it was easy to find the solution. Please note: If you need help to solve a problem, do not believe you know which details are crucial. If you knew, probably you would not need any help in the first place.
